# Basic Search and Replace in Python isn't Executing

Tags: python

I'm trying to code up something in Python, that will simply remove any HTML tags from a string input. But for some reason, the code won't execute (simply hangs) on my home Python install, and gets killed on the Udacity interface.

Where am I going wrong?

```
def remove_tags(sentence):
    list = []
    state = 0
    while state == 0:
        location1 = sentence.find('<')
        location2 = sentence.find('>',location1)
        if location1 != -1:
            chamber = sentence[location1:location2+1]
            sentence.replace(chamber,'')
        elif location1 == -1:
            state = 1
            return sentence.split()
    return sentence.split()

print remove_tags('''<table cellpadding='3'>
                     <tr><td>Hello</td><td>World!</td></tr>
                     </table>''')
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for the `while` loop to terminate, you will need to include a statement that changes the value of `state`.

As it is, you're waiting for there to be no '<' character in `sentence` and returning from inside the `while` loop.  Because you're never changing the value of `sentence`, you're never hitting that `return`.

I find this code confusing because you are using the `state` variable, but it appears you intend the loop to infinite, with the exit happening not in the while, but rather from inside the loop.  If that's your intent, it would be more clearly stated with `while True`.

However, I think the clearest version would be `while '<' in sentence:`.  You can then dispense with the internal `if` statement:

```
while '<' in sentence:
    location1 = sentence.find('<')
    location2 = sentence.find('>',location1)
    chamber = sentence[location1:location2+1]
    sentence = sentence.replace(chamber,'')

return sentence.split()
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed out a line which changes the state when adding into the post. The code still doesn't produce a result sadly. :/

Comment: Choose one control structure -- either the `while` or the internal `return`, and stick to that.  This way is too confusing (at least for an addlepate like myself).

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the replace but not storing the result anywhere, so it is lost.  I assume you mean something like this:

```
sentence = sentence.replace(chamber,'')
```

instead of:

```
sentence.replace(chamber,'')
```

Strings are immutable in Python and so can't be modfied "in place." A new string is always created and so must be assigned to a name if it is to be retained.

Your `while` loop will only exit (via the `return` statement) if it doesn't find `<` in the text, and this will never happen unless the text doesn't contain a `<` character to begin with since, as just described, you are never changing the value of `sentence`.

I'll also mention that your `elif` is redundant. You can just use `else` there and omit the condition, since it's the opposite of the one in your `if`. Furthermore, there's no need for the `state` variable or `list` for that matter (and that's a bad name to begin with).

I'd rewrite your function something like this:

```
def remove_tags(html):
    while '<' in html:
        start = html.find('<')
        end = html.find('>', start)
        tag = html[start:end+1]
        html = html.replace(tag, '', 1)
    return html.split()
```

I have also changed your variable names to better reflect what they're used for.

Of course, this little function will fail to strip what you want if you have any `>` symbols in attributes of your HTML tags. Instead, consider using an HTML parser such as BeautifulSoup to do this.